# I can not get the whole url when the server redirect me by using urllib2.urlopen(url).geturl()

Tags: python, urllib2

For Example, I can only get  `'http://www.stackoverflow.com'` if the **whole** url is `'http://www.stackoverflow.com?key=value&key1=value1'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`urllib2` does **not** strip the query string after a redirect:

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> r = urllib2.urlopen('http://httpbin.org/redirect-to?url=http://example.com/%3Ffoo=bar')
>>> r.geturl()
'http://example.com/?foo=bar'
```

Perhaps you are using a website that redirects you *again* on requests with a query string?

You could use the [`requests` library](https://requests.readthedocs.io/) instead; you can either disable redirects altogether, or you can introspect the history of redirections:

```
>>> import requests 
>>> r = requests.get('http://httpbin.org/relative-redirect/4')
>>> r.history
[<Response [302]>, <Response [302]>, <Response [302]>, <Response [302]>]
>>> r.history[2].url
u'http://httpbin.org/relative-redirect/2'
```